# Javascript, is it possible to have the user input text and images at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if its possible/how to have users input both text and images. I can figure out how to have the user only input text, or only input a file, but I am not sure how to have them insert both (And have them be able to pick where within the text that the image will show up)

Comment: Sounds like you need rich text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903525/rich-text-html-editor-for-websites-i-can-use-for-free

Comment: Are you trying to create a editor where you can insert text as well as image?

Comment: yeah Abhin, pretty much.

Comment: text *and* images, that would be like walking and chewing gum at the same time, can't be done.

Comment: Rich text seems like what I am looking for yup, thanks!